# Does searchbots index content in iframe

Tags: search-engine-indexing, web-crawlers, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we still need to avoid using frame/iframe for good SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/do-we-still-need-to-avoid-using-frame-iframe-for-good-seo)

I have a html page that has a map of a country with lots of dots indicating location of companies through out the country.

The dot's html link code includes the hash-bang + six characters.

When the user clicks on a dot, the following happens:
1) A modal-dialog box displays an iFrame containing another page (from same site).
2) With the dialog box in open state, the "parent's" url changes (adds a hash-bang + six characters) which the user can use to bookmark the page with the dialog-box. When the dialog box closes, the url reverts to the original url.

Am using jQuery and qTip for displaying the modal-dialog box and iframe content (no Ajax is used).

Would the seachbots search/index the content in the iframe?

Answer (score 2):

> IFrames are sometimes used to display content on web pages. Content
>   displayed via iFrames may not be indexed and available to appear in
>   Google's search results. We recommend that you avoid the use of
>   iFrames to display content. If you do include iFrames, make sure to
>   provide additional text-based links to the content they display, so
>   that Googlebot can crawl and index this content.

From the [Google Webmaster Guide](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&query=iframe&answer=72746)

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how you call the modal box - if its an A href .../ link with an ID that is linked to javascrips/jquery, then (in one of my site's case) yes it will be indexed, BUT as its OWN page, ie the content page, not the parent / container.

i got around that by letting google index the iframe content pages, and when a user clicks on the link from a search engine, the page detects that its not within an iframe and redirects back to the parent page.

Comment: Doesn't that mean even search engines will be redirected (assuming they run your JavaScript code, of course)? In which case Google would end up indexing the correct page and not the IFRAME content page?