# Does an iframe count as a backlink to my domain?

Tags: links, seo, iframe

I have the following situation:

**Iframe case** web page *www.notMyWebPage.com* contains an **iframe** that points to my domain (the contents of the iframe are loaded from *www.myWebPage.com*)

**Link case** web page *www.notMyWebPage.com* contains a **link** that points to my domain (it points to *www.myWebPage.com*)

I'd like to know if from the SEO perspective I get the same ranking benefits (i.e., 'juice') **for *www.myWebPage.com*** in the Iframe than in the Link case.

Notice that this question refers to the SEO effect on *www.myWebPage.com*, not on *www.notMyWebPage.com*, which is the subject of concern of [this other question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/do-we-still-need-to-avoid-using-frame-iframe-for-good-seo).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Search engines that recognize and crawl iframes, like Google, should treat this similarly to a backlink. Here's a report confirming this:

[Links In IFrames Pass Value In Google](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-iframe-link-14558.html)

Whether iframe's have the same ranking benefits (i.e., 'juice') as regular backlinks depends on the [attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) and tags used:

[iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) support [Global Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp), including [title](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) which can be used for keywords like anchor text in a link. You can also add them to a longer description in the [longdesc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_longdesc.asp) attribute (not supported in HTML5), which points to a text file. Additionally, you can add keywords to the [noframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noframes.asp) tag (also not supported in HTML5).

So by utilizing these attributes and tags, you can increase the value of the `src` URL of the iframe, just like using anchor text with backlinks. Whether that results in the exact *same* value as a backlink depends on the specific algorithm used by the search engine, but reports seem to indicate they are similarly weighted.