# Can your embeded code on other sites increase seo rank?

Tags: seo, embed

I'm working on a video hosting website and I'm wondering how my embeded code would affect my seo rank

youtube and almost all, major video hosting websites are useing iframe as their embedded code, some of them are using "player" sub domain so, I thought it will be a good practice using player subdomain as things may change in the future.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//player.mywebsite.com/embed/Bp222aodrVg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In my case player.mywebsite.com is actually an CNAME(alias) for mywebsite.com.

will player.mywebsite.com effect the rank of mywebsite.com?

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Google has got better at handling [Frames](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en) since 2010: `Google tries to associate framed content with the page containing the frames, but we don't guarantee that we will.` There are lot of reports to confirm that content in iFrames can be indexed.

Comment: you're right! I'm updating, 60%... I'm reading some interesting articles on it, still there are some loose ends in the way iframes are ranked and the way content is affecting the original page

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Too bad this question got closed (I voted to reopen it). I think you were working on an updated answer, so if you were close to one, maybe you can post it in one of the linked questions as an update there.

Comment: As I commented before, there are still loose ends about iframes, I won't be able to give a reliable answer... sorry :\

Comment: No worries, the question got edited a bit anyway. Just thought it was unfortunate that it got closed if you were still updating your answer. There's some links [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49506/does-an-iframe-count-as-a-backlink-to-my-domain/49515#49515), if you were still interested.