# Does iframe affect SEO of its parent page?

Tags: seo, iframe

I would like to know that, does *iframe* affect the SEO of its parent page (the page contains *iframe*)?

I've done some searching, such as [Do we still need to avoid using frame/iframe for good SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/2267/32051) and [Using iFrame: SEO and Accessibility Points](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/iframe-seo-and-accessibility/15217/), which tell me that:

- **The content in an iframe** is not considered part of the parent page.
- **The page within an iframe** may be spidered and indexed (or it may be
  not) but no PR is definitely passed.

But these are the content **in the iframe**, what about the parent page? Does the PageRank of the parent page will decrease because the *iframe*? Or maybe Googlebot wouldn't crawl the parent page? Or is the parent page not affected at all?

Comment: If the content is not coming from your domain and their are no back links to your page it isn't hurting SEO but you will not reap benefits. If it is spammy info in the iFrame it probably will affect your SEO poorly.

Comment: Googlebot now crawls iFrames and is likely passing pagerank through them: http://www.seroundtable.com/google-iframe-link-14558.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear if Google applies any direct algorithms to a page based on the contents of the iFrames included within that page.

If a page has a crawlable iFrame and that iFrame has hidden links that are meant to deceive Googlebot, then I would be very surprised if Google did not penalize the original page in that case.

You also ask if spam in iFrames could change the ranking of the page.  Any spam that the user can see could change the rankings through user behavior.  If users are not happy with a page (including what they see in its iFrames), they will click the back button.  Google notices when users back out of your site and click on your competitors.

Answer (score 1):

In General the parent page get's none of the page rank of the child (iframe) page. And it's content does not count towards the ranking of the parent page at all.

So a good way to think about it would be say you wrote something on paper in ink. (main page)

Then for part of the page you wrote some on the page in invisible ink (iframe)
And then again more with the regular ink.

Google and other search engines would give the page credit or PR for everything not in the iframe. And no credit for everything in the iframe.

So if your shooting for high PR on the parent page make sure you got good content outside of the iframe.

Comment: Do you mean that, no matter the iframe's content is spam or not, it  doesn't influence the ranking of the parent page, right?

Comment: Got any sources to back this up?