# SEO effects of being embedded on other websites

Tags: seo, iframe

We've recently made some changes so that our site can be included as an iframe widget on other websites.

Can we expect this to give us any SEO boost?

I can only find information about the effect (or lack of effect) that you get from including someone else's iframe in your own site ([this question for example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54169/does-iframe-affect-seo-of-its-parent-page))

Comment: It depends. Does this content link back to your site?

Comment: @JohnConde - we don't link with anchor's - they're all javascript. Should we be adding a few anchor elements in order to get an seo boost (e.g. on our logo)?

Comment: Actually do the opposite. I'll add an answer that will explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google does not like links generated from widgets and will penalize sites that use them](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/09/a-reminder-about-widget-links.html).

> However, some widgets add links to a site that a webmaster did not editorially place and contain anchor text that the webmaster does not control. Because these links are not naturally placed, they're considered a violation of Google Webmaster Guidelines.

So, if by placing this widget on other site you somehow generate incoming links, you run the risk of being penalized by Google. If this does not generate links to your site through the widget it really won't make a difference either way.

To summarize, if your site is just an iframe with no `provided by <link to your site>` you should be okay. But being the content is in an iframe I wouldn't expect any kind of SEO boost.