# Does Awesome Table works well with Search Engines?

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing

Does anyone knows how [AwesomeTable](https://awesome-table.com/) works with search engines? I'm thinking in use it to create a simple catalogue in a site, but it needs to be indexed to be useful to the client.

Comment: It uses Google Sheets which uses IFRAME... See: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54169/does-iframe-affect-seo-of-its-parent-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know AwesomeTable specifically, but if it is in an IFRAME, as Simon says it is in his comment, then you may not get much SEO on your own pages.

Also, if the data is loaded dynamically, the search engines are not unlikely to not load that data. In other words, it would be better if your server generated the data and sends that to the client. That way when a search engines loads your page it includes said data.

Now there are problems with catalogs where they change all the time and thus whatever page you have with such a catalog would anyway be a moving target and for google (or others) to send their users to a page that changes often is a risk as the data in the search query may not be on that page anymore.

So I would instead concentrate on creating one page per product and have those pages indexed rather than dynamical or at least permanently changing pages of lists of content indexed. Actually, those catalog reference pages could even be marked as NOINDEX to avoid having people sent to somewhat senseless pages.

To be noted, Google rarely sends users to such pages now a day. They have new algorithm, I would imagine, that detect pages that are lists of other pages and they try to avoid sending people there. I can still find those pages on the second or third page of Google search results but rarely on the front page. Frankly, it's annoying when you get to a page and your keywords are scattered between 3 or 4 pages and thus the result has nothing to do with the search in the first place.

Having the pages with the catalog is still a good idea since people who like your products will find those very useful, if made obvious enough that they exist and can be used to quickly find any product.

Comment: Thanks. Now i think its better to have more usual page. Awesome Tables would be useful just because it's so easy to use.