# How iframe affect SEO in 2022?

Tags: seo, iframe

Say, we have two static pages: `index.html` and `content.html`.

`index.html` looks like this:

```html
<div>Some static template...</div>
<iframe src="content.html"></iframe>
```

**Question:** will Google parse the whole website including `content.html` and show that in search previews?

I read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file but most people suggest fetching data from JS. I am not SEO, but as I understand, the content either won't be parsed by robots or won't be ranked on top.

Am I correct? Are there any other suggestions how to make it **SEO friendly**?

---

> 1. Most questions are really old like this one *[Does iframe affect SEO of its parent page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54169/does-iframe-affect-seo-of-its-parent-page)*
> 2. The page content.html is hosted **on the same domain**!
> 3. Ideally, I want to override `content.html` occasionally but **it is essential the text on this page to be crawled**.
> 4. My idea is to host a static website on Amazon S3 and update content via API. It is fast, cheap and easy to maintain.

Comment: When you want newer answers to an old question the way Stack Exchange has prescribed to do so is not to ask a new question but to offer a bounty on the already existing question. That way we have one canonical question for the question.

Comment: @JohnConde how to offer a bounty on that question? And what does it mean?

Comment: See [this documentation](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) for what bounties are and how to offer one.