# Current situation around iFrame web and SEO?

Tags: seo, url, keywords, iframe

I was searching the web around for relevant information about this, but all I could find are incomplete or outdated information.

So consider this: You have your typical business website, but every link to static page point to just one iFrame. So there is no navigation outside of the main page. As far as I know, it is important to have good URL links with good keywords, but since everything is iFrame, there are no urls, outside of w-ww.something.com (no /our-producs or /about-us etc., just one parent page). So does that affect negatively the page ranking? I believe the iFrame content is not indexed at all, isn't it?

Comment: This sounds like an old frames design trick that made something like a one page site today. Assuming that I understand your question correctly and these scenarios are at least similar, the old frames method made a mess out of search and would not be advisable. It was probably a short-cut to save time that has ended up costing far more than the time itself.

Comment: If you think there isw better info available about iframes start a bounty on the question this was closed as a dupe of

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is known as a "framed redirect".

There are actually URLs for each page within the frame, browsers don't show them by default.   Search engine robots such as Googlebot **will** find the frame URLs.     Google will consider those URLs to the be the *real* URLs and it will put those URLs into the index.   Google may even choose not to index the domain name at all.

As a result, your website will not end up getting indexed the way you want it to.   Presumably your iframe URLs are not as pretty and less desirable.   They may even be hosted on another domain.   Visitors from search engines will only ever see that other domain.

The state of SEO for frames and iframes hasn't changed much since question was asked: [Do we still need to avoid using frame/iframe for good SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/do-we-still-need-to-avoid-using-frame-iframe-for-good-seo)